# How would I link a recipe_ID with multiple instances of ingredient_ID when creating a recipe database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing a recipe database to be used with a java webapp.

The issue I'm having is assigning multiple rows from the `ingredients` table to individual rows from the `recipes` table. I'm not even sure if it's possible to say something like `recipe_id(1)` corresponds to `ingredient_id(1, 2, 4, 6, 11)`

Comment: You need a third table, called, say `RecipeIngredients` with one row per recipe and per ingredient in that recipe.

Comment: Thanks. So just to clarify - when you say one row per recipe and per ingredient, do you mean a creating an associative table through an `INNER JOIN`?